# Missed files using mv in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, find, mv

I have a script in bash that moves a lot of files from one hard drive to another.
The problem is that sometimes the script generate a lot of files empty in the destination folder and deleted the files in the original folder (I suspect that this happens when the destination disk is full)
This is basically the lines of code that I think they cause the problem:

```
find /mnt/$server/ar/Folder01 -mtime +30 -exec mv -t /home/user/Folder01/$server/ {} \+
find /mnt/$server/ar/Folder02 -mtime +30 -exec mv -t /home/user/Folder02/$server/ {} \+
```

I can't use mv * because the folder have too many files.

Some idea or suggestion?

Comment: You're moving files/directories from a bunch of directories into one directory, ergo anything with the same name can get overwritten.

Comment: Also, are you actually trying to `mv` only files modified more than 30 days ago? If yes, then I'm not sure what you mean by the note `I can't use mv * because the folder have too many files`?

Comment: The filename contains the date of creation of the file, so I try to use mv *october20 for example.

Comment: The question still isn't very clear. What are you trying to do? `mv` files and directories, or just files? What do the files to `mv` look like? Do you expect them to all get `mv`'d into one directory, or to keep the general directory structure? etc...

Comment: I just try to move files(no directories) from one directory to another.

Comment: So something like `find "/mnt/$server/ar/Folder01" -maxdepth 1 -type f -mtime +30 -exec mv -i {} /home/user/Folder01/$server/ +` ?

Comment: The origin folder only has files, so I think that the -maxdepth parameter is not necessary, or I'm wrong?

Comment: Yeah, can omit it, though should keep `-type f`

Answer (score 0):

From `info coreutils mv`

> **mv** can move any type of file from one file system to another.
>   Prior to version *4.0* of the fileutils, *mv* could move only regular
>   files between file systems.  For example, now *mv* can move an entire
>   directory hierarchy including special device files from one partition
>   to another.  It first uses some of the same code that's used by `cp -a`
>   to copy the requested directories and files, then (assuming the copy
>   succeeded) it removes the originals.  **If the copy fails, then the part
>   that was copied to the destination partition is removed.** If you were
>   to copy three directories from one partition to another and the copy of
>   the first directory succeeded, **but the second didn't**, **the first would
>   be left on the destination partition** and the second and third would be
>   left on the original partition.

So it seems that it will delete only if the copy is succeeded.
It should be the opposite for file with 0 size: you should have finished the space in the origin filesystem  instead. (You create a file with its filename but you cannot give it any sector free to write in).
A `sync` before you start to copy can help in the case you have not finished the space but the system is waiting to write the file on the disk (It should not be needed but you can always do it... )